# Changing dataSource URI of WMS RasterLayer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms

I'm trying to change the data source of a QgsRasterLayer to point to a different URI.

I can change the dataProvider's datasource with `wmsLayer.dataProvider().setDataSourceUri(uri)` and the change is correctly shown.

But as it's just changing the dataProvider the change is not saved and will default back on reloading the project. `wmslayer.source()` also still returns the old source.

There is a `QgsRasterLayer::setDataSource()` function, but it doesn't appear to have a python binding.

How would one go about changing it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294675/changing-uri-source-of-wms-raster-layer-in-place-pyqgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Or rather QgsRasterLayer was updated to support  `QgsRasterLayer::setDataSource()` so this works now:

```
rasterlayer.setDataSource(uri, "LAYERNAME", "wms", QgsDataProvider.ProviderOptions())
```

Which is great.